# How to remove the site health dashboard widget?

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard, site-health-widget

WordPress 5.4 introduced the *Site Health Status* dashboard widget ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/2c4480958bc230cbe89978738a26156c5346e785)).

The dashboard widget shows the status of the [site health check](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/04/25/site-health-check-in-5-2/):

[image: Screenshot of dashboard widgets including the site health status]

How can I remove the *Site Health Status* dashboard widget?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following snippet removes the [registered site health dashboard widget](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4-branch/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php#L56) from the dashboard. Add the code to your plugin or `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_site_health_dashboard_widget');
function remove_site_health_dashboard_widget()
{
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_site_health', 'dashboard', 'normal');
}
```

Comment: Hi Sven, it was my understanding that themes & their functions.php files don't have any affect in the admin dashboard. I could be wrong though :) Ignore what I just said, after following the link you provided I discovered the /wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php file and your fix indeed works. Wont it get overwritten with a WP update though?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, the changes should be made in a custom plugin or the child themes `functions.php` file to not get overwritten with the next update.

Comment: By default themes don't manipulate the dashboard however the functions.php file does give you the ability to influence tons of different areas within WordPress, including the dashboard.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, thanks for that info. I wasn't aware functions.php affected dashboards. I would have thought Wordpress wouldn't allow that to stop dodgy code buggering up back-end dashboards. We can break the front-end but always get access to back-end to fix it up. Good to know for future use.

Comment: I'm afraid but is not working for me...

Comment: @David Where did you paste the code? Is the theme/plugin activated?

Comment: It was me... it's working. Thanks

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom you can break whatever you want in wp.

Comment: This widget is wrapped around the permission `view_site_health_checks` as another means of control.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your Dashboard. On the screen showing the "Site Health" widget, click the **"Screen Options"** menu item at the top right of your screen and turn off "Site Health" and any other widgets you don't want to see.

Each time you login the Site Health functions will not appear. This is a per user function, therefore turning it off only removes it for you and not other users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works very well for individual users but I wanted to remove it altogether from the dashboard.

Comment: @Sven, that wasn't clear from the question. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in your `functions.php` will remove Site Health widget from the dashboard:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_site_health_widget' );
function remove_site_health_widget() {
        global $wp_meta_boxes;
        unset( $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_site_health'] );
}
```

And this will remove the respective option from the menu:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_site_health_submenu', 999 );
function remove_site_health_submenu() {
        $page = remove_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'site-health.php' );
}
```

I don't believe that removing Site Health altogether is advisable, though, as it is a nice feature that can help you fix problems that might otherwise be undetected. What I suggest, instead, is [hiding it from everyone except for the main Admin](https://www.gsarigiannidis.gr/how-to-hide-wordpress-site-health-from-everyone-but-you/).

Answer (score 0):

I created a free, lightweight, plugin to solve this issue

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-site-heath-from-dashboard/